# Calculate triangle areas in a loop - R

Tags: r

I have a 20 points (X1, Y1,…. Xn, Yn) on a pyramid and a random base point (Xbase, Ybase). I wish to calculate the triangle area between (Xi, Yi; Xi+1, Yi+1; Xbase, Ybase). Therefore, I did a loop that calculate the area but I can not store the area result area in a the data.frame (myDF). Furthermore, is there another elegant way to calculate the area?

Script:

```
library(ggplot2)

myDF <- data.frame(area=double())

nElem <- 100
xData <- as.data.frame(seq(1,nElem,5))
yData1 <- seq(5,nElem/2,5)
yData2 <- rev(yData1-4)
yData<- as.data.frame((c(yData1, yData2)))
xyDATA<- cbind(xData,yData)
colnames(xyDATA) <- c("xCoord","yCoord")


Xbase <-runif(1, 90, 91)
Ybase <-runif(1, 1.0, 1.5)


for(i in 1:19) 
{
x1 <- Xbase
y1 <- Ybase
x2 <- xyDATA[i,1]
y2 <- xyDATA[i,2]
x3 <- xyDATA[i+1,1]
y3 <- xyDATA[i+1,2]
s <- 0.5*sqrt((x2*x3-x3*y2)^2+(x3*y1-x1*y3)^2+(x1*y2-x2*y1)^2)
myDF[i] <-s
}

P1 <- ggplot(xyDATA) + geom_point(aes(x = xCoord, y = yCoord)) 
P2 <- P1 + geom_point(aes(x = x1, y = y1),colour="red",size=4)
P2
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `myDF` is a data.frame, not a vector, why are you indexing it as such? You could pre-allocate it (since you "know" the size) with `myArea <- numeric(19)` and then assign as `myArea[i] <- s`. Even better, replace `for(i...)` with `myArea <- sapply(1:19, function(i) { x1 ... ; s; })`.

Answer (score 1):

As written you are assigning the value of s to an entire column in the dataframe. You probably want to specify an area column and then assign into a row of that col.

```
  # before the loop, create the column:
  DF['area'] <- NA

# Inside the loop
....
myDF[i, "area"] <-s
```

Comment: OP has already created the column in line 2, so IMHO the first line of code is not needed?

Comment: There is a problem with the area equation. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the dplyr package:

```
nElem <- 100
xData <- as.data.frame(seq(1,nElem,5))
yData1 <- seq(5,nElem/2,5)
yData2 <- rev(yData1-4)
yData<- as.data.frame((c(yData1, yData2)))
xyDATA<- cbind(xData,yData)
colnames(xyDATA) <- c("xCoord","yCoord")

Xbase <-runif(1, 90, 91)
Ybase <-runif(1, 1.0, 1.5)

library(dplyr)

myDF <- xyDATA %>%
          mutate("s" = 0.5*sqrt(
            (xCoord*lead(xCoord)-lead(xCoord)*yCoord)^2+
              (lead(xCoord)*Ybase-Xbase*lead(yCoord))^2+
              (Xbase*yCoord-xCoord*Ybase)^2
            ))


head(myDF)
  xCoord yCoord         s
1      1      5  502.2731
2      6     10  807.6995
3     11     15 1118.5987
4     16     20 1431.4092
5     21     25 1745.1034
6     26     30 2059.2776
```

Comment: There is a problem with the area equation. Any idea what is wrong with the loop?